# Cannot up vote a comment on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, ios-app

I see numbers next to comments but I cannot seem to do anything with them, can we enable comment voting and flagging in iOS app?

Comment: Upvoting of comments is currently not implemented in the alpha. It will be sometime soon though.

Comment: Seemed like a fair enough answer @ArieLitovsky. You can always update it once it's status-completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in the latest version of the app.