# SE app for iOS - "All" communities are not ordered by reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I've been using the *SE app for iOS* for a few weeks now, and I love it to bits. A most welcome addition to my *app library*.  However, I have one minor niggle.

If you select your user avatar in the top left corner, in the left hand sidebar, your *User Profile* appears.

[image: User Profile]

Look at the "Top Communities" section, and you will see the top five communities, that the user is a member of, **ordered by reputation**, as is the custom of the web version. So far, so good.

[image: Top Communities]

Then under "Top Communities" select "All *nn* communities", to bring up all of the SE sites that one is a member of.  The ordering of those sites seems a bit **random**, neither alphabetic, nor by reputation

[image: All communities]

Would it be possible to fix the ordering, so that it is consistent with the web version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I incidentally just discovered and fixed this problem today when fixing [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250993/235711).  The API call for /users/{id}/associated is a little problematic because it is A) a paging API without sorting and a hard page size limit of 100 and B) ordered relatively randomly based on I'm assuming database order but possibly creation date order since they appear similarly.

Fortunately we already have a function that loads the logged in user's associated accounts in bulk so I adapted it in place of the existing paging UI.  This is now available in the beta channel and will be in the next app store build.

[image: Screenshot showing Greenonline's sorted list of sites]

Comment: Thank you, I look forward to the update. I was also going to ask if comments can be voted on, but I see that [it has already been asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220306/cannot-up-vote-a-comment-on-ios-app) and fixed. Excellent work. Well done. Thanks again. :-)