# My Coffee profile is missing from the mobile app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I have 276 rep on [the new Coffee site](http://coffee.stackexchange.com):

[image]

...so it should be right here on my network profile:

[image]

As you can see... it isn't.

I'm also missing profiles for Engineering and Lifehacks. Are new sites not getting added to my list of profiles?

(I can visit those sites manually in the app, but viewing my profile from them crashes the app. And I'd tell you what beta version I'm using, but tapping about crashes the app too.)

Comment: In the iPhone app (maybe just the beta?) you can also see the app version number by pulling down on the main menu. I don't know if the same functionality is in the iPad app? Just a little closer to hand than the about menu. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long neglected bug with a lot of related bugs (where are meta sites? Why does your coffee profile show your top posts and about me from Coffee under Meta Stack Exchange?, etc) so I gave it a big overhaul:

First off, your profile displays the right information!

[image: A screenshot showing Abby's Coffee network profile with the correct "All 138" sites text]

Second off, tapping "All **138** sites" takes you to a list including both Coffee and its meta site:

[image: A screenshot showing Abby's communities with Coffee and Coffee Meta visible]

And finally since you probably don't want to scroll through the list hopelessly looking for a site, I threw in search for good measure:

[image: A screenshot showing search in action]

And let's make it look good on iPad too:

[image]

Comment: Woot! Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the iOS app can show only 100 accounts:

> [image]

Might be an API limit, or a simple overlook - one is by design, one is a bug that can be easily fixed. :)

Comment: I suppose it's a pretty rare case for someone to have more than 100 accounts :)

Comment: @abby that's true, but worth to mention that was the case for the web version profile as well and [was fixed about a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227300/152859), hence there's good chance it's just an overlook of the iOS dev team. :)